# Find knee by intersecting line method

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, mathematical-optimization, signal-processing

I have an x-y data list. The data is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VjnDeBFY_cNjNHhvmGlcrBXxGD81D2Ou/edit?usp=drive_link&ouid=111559226469284134444&rtpof=true&sd=true). It looks like below:
[image]

I want to mark the knee location. I mean I need to find the point of greatest slope change and get the x coordinate of this point. Theoretically, this position is around x=29.2519.

I tried SavitzkyGolayMatrix method and get the below result (x=29.4461). This result is a little deviation from the theoretical result x=29.2519.
[image]

I read some literature. Find them with a method: a least squares fit method, find the knee by intersecting two straight lines. And they show the below similar pictures:
[image]

Can someone tell me how to implement this method? Thank you!

Comment: Ummm... what's the "SG" method?

Comment: A result of x=29.4461 seems o.k. considering the noise.

Comment: I'm confused. The plots show such a big range that the presumed knee at around x=29 isn't visible. If you expect it to be there, why not restrict the data range up to, e.g., x=50?